# Everything is Null / 0 / false when I build in Visual Studio Release mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, pointers, sfml

I'm making a game in C++ with Visual Studio 2010 and SFML, and everything works fine when I build on Debug Mode. A few days ago I tried in Release mode and worked fine too, but now everytime I try to build it on Release mode it keeps crashing and showing a message that says something like this:

"Exception not controlled in 0x733b1ed7 in HunterQuest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access infraction when reading the ubication 0x10127459."

Seeing the Local Variables window it looks that everything is pointing to "0x00000000", or it's false or 0...

It crashes at the beginning of my class "Game", that is the only class I use from main(). After a few lines there's this "for", that crashes when i=18. Even if I delete that for, it crashes when I set the float "gravity" to 0.75...

```
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
{
    debug = new Debug();
    debug->Inicializar(fuenteMine, sf::Color::Black, 12);
    listaDebug.push_back(debug);
}

haPulsadoN = false;
haPulsadoP = false;
puedePulsarU = true;
juegoPausado = false;
puedeQuitarVida = false;

gravedad = 0.75;
tipoCam = 1;
nCuadrante = 1;
```

Any idea of what's happening?

EDIT: I don't know if this could help but this is the first line in my Constructor of Juego (my Game class), it has a few more lines but I want to point this:

```
Juego::Juego()
{
    ventana = new Ventana(1024, 768);
}
```

And this is the Constructor of Ventana:

```
Ventana::Ventana(int an, int al) 
{
    ancho = an;
    alto = al;

    ventana = new sf::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode(ancho, alto), "Hunter's Quest");
}
```

Instead 1024 for "ancho" and 768 for "alto", they are "13327667" each one inside the constructor, and when I move line by line with F10 (debugging it) it jumps directly from "ancho = an;" to "ventana = new", so it doesn't apply "an" and "al"....I don't know why...

Comment: Did you link to the *release* libraries of SFML when you switched your program to release mode?

Comment: Yes, I linked them a few days ago. I tried then and worked fine, and I haven't touched them.

Comment: @Mehdow You can't properly debug a release build that is optimized.  That's probably why you don't see the variables and code is skipped.  The code no longer matches the source, since the compiler optimized the code.  If you want to debug a release build, turn off the optimizations and rebuild.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I see, thanks. But even If I shouldn't focus in the variables, I still not knowing why It crashes there (doing a for or setting a float) and what could be the problem...

Comment: @Mehdow No one will know why anything crashes with the little bit of code you posted.  Why not display the values using OutputDebugString() or other tracing facilities, and not use the debugger?  Then your post would be more relevant as you will really know what the real values are.  Right now, your post is conveying invalid information to others reading your post.  So I would suggest you change your program to log or display those values and then edit your question to show us what those values really are.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Sorry, you're right. But I managed to make it working again, it was a mistake I did in some point of my code, but I didn't know that if I'm on Release mode I will not see the variables properly and I thought It was Visual Studio fault. Thank's for the help, I didn't even know I could enable and disable the optimization of Release mode. That helped me a lot.